# Refund part order but don't refund shipping

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, refund

at the moment I have a function which will refund the invoice on an order. However the shipping is currently also being refunded, which I don't want.
Is there a way to set the shipping to zero on an invoice refund?

My code is currently this:

```
private function createCreditMemoItem($item)
{
    $creditmemoItem = $this->creditmemoItemFactory->create();
    $creditmemoItem->setOrderItemId($item->getId());
    $creditmemoItem->setQty($item->getQtyOrdered());

    return $creditmemoItem;
}

private function refundItems($order,$items) {
        $refundItems = $items;
        $items = [];

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if (!in_array($item->getId(), $refundItems)) {
                continue;
            }

            // create creditmemo item and add to array
            $creditmemoItem = $this->createCreditmemoItem($item);
            $items[] = $creditmemoItem;
        }
        
        // get the invoice id

        $invoiceId = null;

        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
            // this will always point to the latest invoice id
            $invoiceId = $invoice->getId();
        }

        // refund the invoice
        $this->refundInvoice->execute(
            $invoiceId,
            $items,
            true, // false = offline / true = online
            true // notify customer
        );
    }
```

the `refundInvoice` uses the `Magento\Sales\Api\RefundInvoiceInterface` class.

So just to re-iterate, the partial refund works fine in the sense that, the individual items chosen are refunded but like I say, the shipping amount is also being refunded, which I don't want to happen :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Hello, I am making a return module as well and following your example it returns this error `Exception #0 (Magento\Sales\Exception\DocumentValidationException): Creditmemo Document Validation Error(s):
We can't create creditmemo for the invoice.`, This if I don't use the `$ this-> createCreditmemoItem ($ item);` part, but if I include it, the `createCreditmemoItem` function gives me an error, where does this function come from? How do I add it to my controller?

Comment: Hi @EdwinAquino I have updated the question code above to show the missing createCreditmemoItem() method at the top. To use that method, you will also need to DI an instance of `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory` into your class.

Comment: This error returns `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory::create()` It is as if the create method does not exist in the class that I import

Comment: Very strange. Do you have any of your code I can look at to see if I can identify the issue for you?

Comment: I could already find how using this class `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\ItemCreation;`, But now I have another problem, the return is created well, but if I do not return the shipping amount, the order still does not go to the closed state, and if I manually set the state with `$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CLOSED)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CLOSED);`, Changes the status to closed, but does not return the order

Comment: One of the things which caught me out (when testing on local) was when you've created the order, ensure that an invoice is raised as "offline" if on local. Then when you run your script to part refund the order, a credit memo should be raised and then the refund will be actioned. Can you confirm if you are getting this far without any errors?

Comment: Yes, so far it goes without errors, the error actually appeared when I included the part to change the status by hand after the refund method is executed

Comment: Try including 
`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\CreationArgumentsFactory` 
into your class. Then Set your arguments using something like:
$arguments = $this->creditmemoArguments->create();
$arguments->setShippingAmount(0);

Comment: Then in your `refundInvoice` call, add in the new parameter, e.g:

`$this->refundInvoice->execute($invoiceId, $items, true, true, false, null, $arguments);`

Comment: I already have that method included in the code, and the state does not change anyway, what I guess is that for the internal magento process an order cannot be closed if the total number of articles has not been returned and shipping

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured this one out :D 
So basically when we run the `execute` method on the **refundInvoice** object, we need to send some arguments with it also.

We can set those arguments using the **Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\CreationArgumentsFactory** model.

If we assign the model to a **$creationArguments** property
We can then set the shipping amount in the following way:

```
$arguments = $this->creationArguments->create();
$arguments->setShippingAmount(0); // don't refund the shipping when creating the credit memo

 // refund the invoice
$this->refundInvoice->execute(
    $invoiceId,
    $items,
    true, // false = offline / true = online
    true, // notify customer
    false, // append comment
    null, // CreditmemoCommentCreationInterface
    $arguments
);
```

I hope this helps someone else out who hit the same problem as I did :)